# Can I create a Möbius strip from two equilateral triangles?

Tags: geometry, mobius-band

Is it possible to take two equilateral triangles in the configuration [depicted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkSo4.jpg)
and create a moebius strip by connecting up the points of the traingles in a certain order. I'm working in a 3d app(Houdini) and am asking for a client to find out if this shape is even possible, and if so what kind of maths i'd need to learn to program it.

Would really appreciate any help as i'm way out of my depth here.

The margin of the desired mobius strip is shown in yellow [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQ5mH.jpg)

The surface of the strip should also align with the green lines connecting the points of the opposing triangles as show [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hSZo.jpg)

The locations of each triangles vertices in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCkrY.jpg)

Currently I am trying to solve this by connecting the points together in the order show, then resampling the resulting curve and copying lines to it and then converting them to a [surface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Re2YF.jpg):

latest attempt following suggestions: [image]

Comment: In your image it isn't clear what are the triangles. A triangle in geometry does *not* include its interior points, only the three vertices and three edges. Your red and blue triangles seem to overlap, but the picture does not make it clear how they do. It might be better for you to give the coordinates of all six vertices involved. Note that if to start with any edge of one triangle actually intersects with an edge of the other triangle then the filling out is already impossible.

Comment: Hi @coffeemath thanks for your response! yes, the triangles edges do indeed intersect.

Comment: In your picture, edges (0,2) and (0,4) of the blue triangle do not even meet any red colored points. And the only point where edge (2,4) meets any red point is at the midpoint of (2,4), however that point is not on any of the three edges of the red triangle. So no. in your picture the triangle edges do *not* meet. It's a good thing they do not meet, because if they did it would be hard to see how there would be a chance to "fill out" the wireframe made by the two triangles in space into a Mobius band.

Comment: Right those edges on the triangles dont meet any other points, i've added another image to the post which depicts how they want to connect the points

Comment: Now it seems like an interesting problem. I have a question and a suggestion. Ques: Did you get this set-up from a text or other source which then asked one to fill in the band? [If so cite source] Sugg: You had better include *in the post itself* some of your own attempt at solving it. Otherwise the question will be closed, there's already 1 close vote.

Comment: Yeah the diagram is from the client and they are asking me to fill the band which i'm currently approaching by copying lines to that margin along the bitangent and then converting them to polygons - i don't really know how to include my own attempts at solving it in the post as i'm working just inside this 3d app but i'll have a go - thanks again!

Comment: You mention connecting the edges of the triangle, yet your diagram has a yellow line connecting their vertices. That yellow line seems to form a trefoil knot. What do you mean by "margin of a mobius strip"? Do you mean the line should form the edge of the strip? If so, then that is not possible since the edge of a normal mobius strip is not knotted.

Comment: On the other hand you could of course have a mobius strip whose centre line followed that yellow path.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis my bad, that should be connect the points of the triangle with a line that forms the edge of the strip - thanks for your response, it does indeed seem impossible to me but not having any knowledge of maths i couldnt say for sure.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! <> Do the triangles (either filled or unfilled) have any relation to the desired Moebius strip (e.g., the triangles' edges lie on the strip, or their interiors compose part of the strip) other than by their vertices lying on the strip's boundary? (IIRC, a Moebius strip with _three_ half-twists has a trefoil knot as boundary. This does not contradict Jaap's comment, since a "normal" strip has one half-twist.)

Comment: Hi @AndrewD.Hwang - no as far as i understand it the only relation of the triangles to the strip is that their points when connected form its edge, although they have given instructions to join each of the triangles points to the corresponding point of the other triangle and have these lines align with the surface of the strip if possible, i'll attach their diagram of that to the main post

Comment: the strip should not intersect the triangles, but it can intersect itself

Comment: If you're ok with a Mobius strip that has three half turns rather than a single half turn, then the trefoil path is perfect. Let a point travel along the trefoil path at such speeds that it hits the vertices at regular intervals. Now do that with two points, starting at vertices connected with a green line segment. As the points move, the green segment traces out a surface that forms a mobius strip with three twists. I think it might slightly intersect the red triangle on the right hand end though, but maybe the yellow path can be tweaked to avoid that.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis thankyou so much for this! I'm attempting to put that together now, will attach to the original post.